# Highlighting specific instances of a string for output to TextArea

Tags: java, javafx

I have a search function that scrolls through a String and finds specific instances of a substring and then notes the index for the location of the substring.

For example, if I'm trying to find the String

```
"AATACG"
```

in the string

```
"TACGATCAATACGACGATCAGT",
```

it will return 7 as the index of the substring. What I need is a way to color the substring. So, the return text will be

```
"TACGATCAATACGACGATCAGT",
```

but with the substring colored. The text is outputted to a JavaFX TextArea.

I've tried using ANSI codes (which didn't work); I've also tried changing the string into a Text object and setting the fill color/applying a CSS id, but I can't find a way to change the Text back into a String with the color change remaining.

Is there a way to do this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: You cannot do this with a `TextArea`. You need a third-party control such as [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX)

Comment: Yes, RichTextFX has `area.setStyleClass(from, to, "red");`.

Comment: @JoopEggen I've found RichTextFX, but I can't run either of the .jar files (Yosemite).

Comment: @apizzimenti You might want to edit your question and tell us what you have tried and what doesn't work with `RichTextFX`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [javafx.scene.text.TextFlow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html)? Seems like you want to highlight text without editing it. In this case `TextFlow` is appropriate component.